# Trying to create an SQL Server geometry instance using STGeomFromText() and a MultiPolygon but the created geometry instance is invalid

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, geometry, sqlgeometry

I'm trying to create a geometry instance in `SQL Server` using `STGeomFromText()` and a `MultiPolygon` but I keep getting an invalid instance. What is wrong with the `MultiPolygon`?

```
DECLARE @area0 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((-123.140037 49.16519, -123.140034 49.165778, -123.140033 49.165874, -123.140032 49.166088, -123.13973 49.166088, -123.139685 49.166088, -123.13969 49.166244, -123.139467 49.16639, -123.13947 49.166784, -123.139395 49.166835, -123.139394 49.166935, -123.139394 49.166993, -123.139393 49.167049, -123.139392 49.167146, -123.139323 49.16719, -123.139322 49.167209, -123.13932 49.167433, -123.139301 49.167671, -123.139303 49.168716, -123.13922 49.168716, -123.139202 49.169448, -123.138172 49.169443, -123.137973 49.16944, -123.137813 49.169336, -123.137777 49.169334, -123.137692 49.169333, -123.137706 49.168571, -123.137711 49.168303, -123.137581 49.168302, -123.136944 49.168296, -123.136937 49.168017, -123.136937 49.167975, -123.136935 49.167931, -123.13693 49.167742, -123.137292 49.167739, -123.137389 49.167738, -123.137476 49.167737, -123.137553 49.167737, -123.137648 49.167736, -123.137651 49.167673, -123.137644 49.16741, -123.137593 49.167373, -123.137593 49.167317, -123.137593 49.167266, -123.137594 49.167046, -123.137595 49.166987, -123.137594 49.16693, -123.137595 49.166603, -123.137632 49.166578, -123.137735 49.166579, -123.137736 49.166428, -123.137737 49.166233, -123.137737 49.166171, -123.137737 49.166093, -123.137661 49.166092, -123.137597 49.166049, -123.137598 49.165823, -123.137598 49.165781, -123.137598 49.165727, -123.137599 49.165437, -123.137601 49.165059, -123.137518 49.165055, -123.137479 49.165022, -123.137487 49.164497, -123.137528 49.164464, -123.139088 49.164475, -123.139092 49.164817, -123.138908 49.164818, -123.13891 49.164915, -123.138789 49.164913, -123.138785 49.165064, -123.139014 49.16507, -123.139018 49.165188, -123.139049 49.165188, -123.140037 49.16519), (-123.137288 49.168425, -123.137253 49.168676, -123.13689 49.168676, -123.136865 49.168425, -123.137288 49.168425), (-123.137771 49.169962, -123.136839 49.16997, -123.136823 49.169063, -123.137193 49.169055, -123.137184 49.169383, -123.137412 49.169391, -123.137424 49.169538, -123.137754 49.169539, -123.137771 49.169962)))', 4326); 
SELECT @area0.STIsValid(); --This results in 0
```

Eventually I want to use @area0 in SQL Server like this:
`@area0.STIntersects(table.Shape) = 1`

When I use the same `MultiPolygon` in `Snowflake` using `to_geography()`, I get a valid instance.

```
SELECT ST_ISVALID(to_geography(
  'MULTIPOLYGON (((-123.140037 49.16519, -123.140034 49.165778, -123.140033 49.165874, -123.140032 49.166088, -123.13973 49.166088, -123.139685 49.166088, -123.13969 49.166244, -123.139467 49.16639, -123.13947 49.166784, -123.139395 49.166835, -123.139394 49.166935, -123.139394 49.166993, -123.139393 49.167049, -123.139392 49.167146, -123.139323 49.16719, -123.139322 49.167209, -123.13932 49.167433, -123.139301 49.167671, -123.139303 49.168716, -123.13922 49.168716, -123.139202 49.169448, -123.138172 49.169443, -123.137973 49.16944, -123.137813 49.169336, -123.137777 49.169334, -123.137692 49.169333, -123.137706 49.168571, -123.137711 49.168303, -123.137581 49.168302, -123.136944 49.168296, -123.136937 49.168017, -123.136937 49.167975, -123.136935 49.167931, -123.13693 49.167742, -123.137292 49.167739, -123.137389 49.167738, -123.137476 49.167737, -123.137553 49.167737, -123.137648 49.167736, -123.137651 49.167673, -123.137644 49.16741, -123.137593 49.167373, -123.137593 49.167317, -123.137593 49.167266, -123.137594 49.167046, -123.137595 49.166987, -123.137594 49.16693, -123.137595 49.166603, -123.137632 49.166578, -123.137735 49.166579, -123.137736 49.166428, -123.137737 49.166233, -123.137737 49.166171, -123.137737 49.166093, -123.137661 49.166092, -123.137597 49.166049, -123.137598 49.165823, -123.137598 49.165781, -123.137598 49.165727, -123.137599 49.165437, -123.137601 49.165059, -123.137518 49.165055, -123.137479 49.165022, -123.137487 49.164497, -123.137528 49.164464, -123.139088 49.164475, -123.139092 49.164817, -123.138908 49.164818, -123.13891 49.164915, -123.138789 49.164913, -123.138785 49.165064, -123.139014 49.16507, -123.139018 49.165188, -123.139049 49.165188, -123.140037 49.16519), (-123.137288 49.168425, -123.137253 49.168676, -123.13689 49.168676, -123.136865 49.168425, -123.137288 49.168425), (-123.137771 49.169962, -123.136839 49.16997, -123.136823 49.169063, -123.137193 49.169055, -123.137184 49.169383, -123.137412 49.169391, -123.137424 49.169538, -123.137754 49.169539, -123.137771 49.169962)))'
    )
 ); --This results in TRUE
```

Which I then use in Snowflake like this:
`ST_INTERSECTS("DB"."PUBLIC"."TEMP_TABLE".Polygon, table.Centroid)`

Comment: I don't work with the Geometry type to any great extent. If you run `SELECT @area0.MakeValid().ToString()` do the changes it has made to it shed any light?

Comment: I'm going to untag Snowflake, as the question is for SQL server (and I'm glad this works great within Snowflake)

Comment: You can run select @area0.IsValidDetailed() to see what the issue is

Comment: The polygon looks weird to me, it's kinda inverted

Comment: @MartinSmith Is MakeValid() safe to use? It changes the coordinates slightly but when I map it online the shape is similar.

Comment: @siggemannen The detailed error is `24411: Not valid because ring (2) lies outside the exterior ring (1) of its polygon. The problem occurs in entry (2) in a geometry collection.`

Comment: @lptr I need to use geometry because after creating the instance I do `@area0.STIntersects(table.Shape) = 1` where `table.Shape` is of geometry type in the DB.